# Not play stream as a manually in ROKU?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I used a by default media player in Roku. And I stop streaming to other side is stop video from Roku player and again I resume streaming from other side not reload a stream again anyone find this issue on Roku. I used url tag to play a stream. And write into a item tag. I test same thing on VLC media player it's working fine.

Comment: Hi - can you please add some more detail? And include any code you have that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I edit my post. This issue is not required for code.

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are asking. Can you please better describe the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing roku channel, almost all of the things you have to handle in code. In the case that you are asking (what is happening actually), when roku media player don't receive the stream (i.e. when you are stopping the stream from media server), it changes the '**state**' of video player to "error" and generates error data (i.e. errorCode,errorMsg etc). After **'error'** state, roku media player generates **'finished'** (Please go throw the "Video" node documentation for roku development). Second you cannot resume the stream in roku. After error generation you have to close and relaunch the video player.

Comment: Thank you for your reply any solution from this issues

Comment: Yes you can again set the control to "play" after receiving 'error'. But its not recommended, because it can form an infinite loop that can lead to crashing the channel. If it is needed really, than try to limit the number of retries on receiving error.

Comment: any solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817729/live-stream-in-roku In this case same solution or any different scenario available for this.